# Why to use asp.net mvc with TDD?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tdd

Why should I use ASP.NET MVC with `TDD`?

Which are the advantage of TDD? Why it is suitable for MVC to use this kind of approach?

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET MVC offers an alternative to traditional WebForms development. It gives a clear separation of concerns in the application which makes code easier to test. In contrast to WebForms, in ASP.NET MVC infrastructure classes such as [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) are abstracted and could be mocked in unit tests to simulate request handling. You also have much more control over the generated HTML which is a good thing in case you want to comply with standards.

Due to the separation TDD could be applied. In this iterative process, unit tests are written to validate the code against a list of specifications. In the first stages of development writing unit tests might seem to slow down the process but as the code grows its benefits become clearer as you no longer need manually test every aspect of the application once you modify or refactor something.

Comment: I just want to add that if you do employ TDD it is much easier to see what you need to investigate, which requirements are lacking enough definition, and where your natural boundaries are. When you start your process by writing a unit test, you really have to think about what you want to implement, which yields - at least in my experience - much more robust solutions.

Answer (score 2):

### Testablity and TDD

Compared to ASP.NET testing ([unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)) is much, much easier.

Plus on a side note, I enjoy having full control over the HTML output to the users browser. Rather than the mess that ASP.NET auto generates for you.

ASP.NET MVC is a joy to use in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

They are a natural combination :)

ASP.NET WebForms is not friendly to TDD. MVC makes it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Asp.net mvc with TDD:**

This walkthrough shows you how to develop an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio using the test-driven development (TDD) approach. MVC was designed to enable testability without requiring dependencies on a Web server (IIS), on a database, or on external classes. (This is in contrast to unit tests for Web Forms pages, which require a Web server.)

In this walkthrough, you will create tests for an MVC controller before you implement the controller functionality. You can write tests before you have a controller. The advantage is that compiler errors in your unit tests are then a first-level form of unit-test failure. The emphasis is on how to design the intent of the controller by writing unit tests before implementing the controller itself, which is an important aspect of the TDD philosophy.

**Test-driven development:**

Test-driven development (TDD) attempts to resolve this problem and produce higher quality, well-tested code by putting the cart before the horse and writing the tests before we write the code. One of the core practices of Extreme Programming (XP), TDD is acquiring a strong following in the Java community, but very little has been written about doing it in .NET

****one advantage according to my experience is that:**

1. When You are refactoring code ..it will TDD help to find impact of change on other modules or Codes.
2. Other advantage is if you are developing application with TDD with proper test methods application is more stable(stable means minimum bugs) than simple development.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID is a set of design principles that we constantly think about and try to follow when writing good production code.

SOLID stands for (Single responsibility principle, Open-closed principle, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency Injection).

What makes TDD great when writing an ASP.NET project (or any projects for that matter) is that by following TDD you automatically create code that follows the SOLID principles.

SOLID code will make your code easily changeable, less brittle, easy to maintain and flexible.  = Great code.